# Mail.app - Shortcut to switch signatures?

Tags: keyboard, mail.app

Is there a keyboard shortcut (or way to set one) that allows to easily switch between different email signatures in mail.app ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry to dig up an old question, but I had the identical issue today and this was the first result for my google search for “mac mail signature shortcut”. While these answers weren’t what I was looking for, the 3rd google result was a [MacWorld hint](http://www.macworld.com/article/1137144/mailsend.html), which offered the perfect solution.

Here’s the answer: you can assign keyboard shortcuts for your email signatures, “From:” account selection, and even SMTP account from System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts → Application Shortcuts. To set up your shortcut, click the `+` icon, select “Mail.app” from the Application drop down, enter the text of the signature (or other option) as it appears in the New Message window drop down, and give it a keyboard shortcut. Rob Griffiths, the author of the MacWorld hint, advises using `⌃` (`control`) in combination with your desired keys to avoid conflicts with existing Mail shortcuts, which seems smart.

In my case, I created a shortcut in Mail.app for the menu title “None” (the first option under signatures) and assigned it the shortcut `⌃X`. It is now exceedingly easy for me to clear my default email signature when it doesn’t seem appropriate.

For the purposes of illustration, here is the System Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts pane (it’s the last item): [image: Screenshot of System Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts pane]

And here is what it looks like in Mail’s New Message window: [image: Screenshot of Mail’s New Message window]

Answer (score 1):

In "System Preferences", go to "Language & Text."  Under the "Text" button, you have "Symbol & Text Substitution." You should be able to setup a substitution there.

Having said that, I use [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/), which is also a paid app ($35). I find it to be very worthwhile.

Comment: But the "Language & Text." configuration isn't working with Mail or any other useful Apps - only with TextEdit.app

Comment: Adium works with it. iChat doesn't. Mail doesn't. TextEdit does. There is an interesting collection of apps (even first-party) that don't support it. I'm sure there's a specific technical reason for it, I just don't know the class names and functions well enough to comment on that specifically. Also, TextExpander is mentioned heavily when on subjects such as this.

Answer (score 0):

I use [TypeIt4Me](http://www.ettoresoftware.com/products/typeit4me/) for all kind of text - also for my mail signatures. It is like in the AutoCorrect in Word where you type some characters, and they become replaced with the actual word/phrase - this one just work in all Applications.

Another one that do the same replace thing is [Typinator](http://www.ergonis.com/products/typinator/) - but I haven't tried that one my self.

They are both paid Apps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was hoping for a built-in solution but i'll take a look at these