# Mail.app: How can Choose Signature choice be based on recipient?

Tags: keyboard, mail.app

I have different mail signatures that I'd like to use, depending on whether my recipient is internal or external.  In the Signatures tab of Mail.app preferences, I can choose random or sequential only.

Has anyone set this up?  Anyone have any pointers on how to get started on something like this?  Even being able to choose signatures via keyboard shortcut would be an improvement.

Comment: I did notice http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11822/mail-app-shortcut-to-switch-signatures, but I'd prefer to do this automatically, and that one's not answered either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have heard on different podcasts of users who use [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/) to shortcut into typing different e-mail signatures.

TextExpander is on my wish list of apps I will buy soon, I see a lot of potential in having keyboard shortcuts for common text snippets. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll 2nd TextExpander as a good solution here.  You could have a snippet for 'isig' for internal and 'esig' for external

Comment: In 10.7, of course, you can do this without TextExpander -- just set up your common snippets in System Prefs > Language & Text > Text. (The pref pane doesn't give you much room for text input, but you can just copy and paste from TextEdit or similar as required.)

Comment: I noticed people recommending TextExpander.  It's simple enough to hit the signature drop down and switch, but I was hoping that someone had figured out a way to do this in an automated fashion.

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on "Full Keyboard Access" for "All Controls" in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts you can use Tab to navigate to the signature drop down. Or if you have already typed your message, Shift-Tab. Then use arrow keys to select the desired signature.

I've made my simple signature the default, and if I'd like to switch to the formal "external" signature, when finished with the email, I type shift-tab, and then the down arrow.